# Array to string conversion - Validation rule for eloquent

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to validate a field using "in" and then passing an array befored defined. But when creating I get this error

> "message": "Array to string conversion",
>
> "exception": "ErrorException",

If I comment out the line where I use the validation, then works. So I'm pretty sure the problem is that.

I've seen another related posts, but they didn't work.

Thank you.

```php
CONST ARRAY_EXAMPLES = [
    'example1'  => 0,
    'example2'  => 1,
    'example3'   => 2,
    'example4'  => 3,
    'example5' => 4,
    'example6'  => 5,
];

protected $fillable = [
    'array_example'
];
'array_example' => 'int|in:' .array_values(self::ARRAY_EXAMPLES)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you concatenate two expressions in php both of them are casting to strings. But there is no any built in way to cast array to string. So you can't [concatenate string and array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting) here:

```
'int|in:' .array_values(self::ARRAY_EXAMPLES)
```

But you can convert array to string by [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
'int|in:' . implode(',', self::ARRAY_EXAMPLES)
```